# Parse the string into a list of tuples

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I am looking for a piece of code in F# that can parse this type of string:

"x=1,y=42,A=[1,3,4,8]"

into a list of tuples that looks like this:

[("x",1);("y",42);("A",1);("A",3);("A",4);("A",8)]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post whatever code you've tried?

Answer (score 5):

You can quite nicely solve this using the [FParsec](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) parser combinator library. This is manageable using regular expressions, but it's not very elegant. Parser combinators make it very clear what the grammar of the inputs that you can handle is. You can also easily add other features like whitespace.

The following actually produces a list of `string * Value` pairs where `Value` is a new data type, corresponding to the possible right-hand-sides in the input:

```
type Value = Int of int | List of int list
```

Now, you can do the parsing using the following:

```
let ident = identifier (IdentifierOptions())

let rhs = 
  // Right-hand-side is either an integer...
  ( pint32 |>> Int ) <|>
  // Or a list [ .. ] of integers separated by ','
  ( pchar '[' >>. (sepBy pint32 (pchar ',')) .>> pchar ']' |>> List ) 

let tuple = 
  // A single tuple is an identifier = right-hand-side
  ident .>> pchar '=' .>>. rhs

let p = 
  // The input is a comma separated list of tuples
  sepBy tuple (pchar ',')

run p "x=1,y=42,A=[1,3,4,8]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a named regex makes for readable code, even if not the regex.

```
(?<id>\w+)=((\[((?<list>(\d+))*,?\s*)*\])|(?<number>\d+))
```

This reads: *Identifier* = [*Number* followed by comma or space, zero or more] | *Number*

```
let parse input =
    [
        let regex = Regex("(?<id>\w+)=((\[((?<list>(\d+))*,?\s*)*\])|(?<number>\d+))")
        let matches = regex.Matches input

        for (expr : Match) in matches do
            let group name = expr.Groups.[string name]
            let id = group "id"
            let list = group "list"
            let number = group "number"
            if list.Success then
                for (capture : Capture) in list.Captures do
                    yield (id.Value, int capture.Value)
            else if number.Success then
                yield (id.Value, int number.Value)
    ]
```

**Test**

```
let input = "var1=1, var2=2, list=[1, 2, 3, 4], single=[1], empty=[], bad=[,,], bad=var"    
printfn "%A" (parse input)
```

**Output**

```
[("var1", 1); ("var2", 2); ("list", 1); ("list", 2); ("list", 3); ("list", 4); "single", 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite advisable to follow the approach outlined by [Tomas Petricek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60919791), employing the established FParsec parser combinator library.

For educational purposes, you might want to roll your own parser combinator, and for this endeavor Scott W.'s blog (["Understanding parser combinators"](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators/), and ["Building a useful set of parser combinators"](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/understanding-parser-combinators-2/)) contains valuable information.

The parsing looks quite similar:

```
// parse a list of integers enclosed in brackets and separated by ','
let plist = pchar '[' >>. sepBy1 pint (pchar ',') .>> pchar ']'
// parser for the right hand side, singleton integer or a list of integers
let intOrList = pint |>> (fun x -> [x]) <|> plist
// projection for generation of string * integer tuples
let ungroup p =
    p |>> List.collect (fun (key, xs) -> xs |> List.map (fun x -> key, x))
// parser for an input of zero or more string value pairs separated by ','
let parser = 
    sepBy (letters .>> pchar '=' .>>. intOrList) (pchar ',')
    |> ungroup

"x=1,y=42,A=[1,3,4,8]"
|> run parser
// val it : ((String * int) list * string) option =
//   Some ([("x", 1); ("y", 42); ("A", 1); ("A", 3); ("A", 4); ("A", 8)], "")
```

This simple grammar still requires 15 or so parser combinators. Another difference is that for simplicity's sake the `Parser` type has been modeled on FSharp's `Option` type.

```
type Parser<'T,'U> = Parser of ('T -> ('U * 'T) option)

let run (Parser f1) x =     // run the parser with input
    f1 x

let returnP arg =           // lift a value to a Parser
    Parser (fun x -> Some(arg, x))

let (>>=) (Parser f1) f =   // apply parser-producing function
    Parser(f1 >> Option.bind (fun (a, b) -> run (f a) b))

let (|>>) p f =             // apply function to value inside Parser
    p >>= (f >> returnP)

let (.>>.) p1 p2 =          // andThen combinator
    p1 >>= fun r1 ->
    p2 >>= fun r2 ->
    returnP (r1, r2)

let (.>>) p1 p2 =           // andThen, but keep first value only
    (p1 .>>. p2) |>> fst

let (>>.) p1 p2 =           // andThen, keep second value only
    (p1 .>>. p2) |>> snd

let pchar c =               // parse a single character
    Parser (fun s -> 
        if String.length s > 0 && s.[0] = c then Some(c, s.[1..])
        else None )

let (<|>) (Parser f1) (Parser f2) =     // orElse combinator
    Parser(fun arg ->
        match f1 arg with None -> f2 arg | res -> res )

let choice parsers =        // choose any of a list of combinators
    List.reduce (<|>) parsers

let anyOf =                 // choose any of a list of characters
    List.map pchar >> choice

let many (Parser f) =       // matches zero or more occurrences
    let rec aux input =
        match f input with
        | None -> [], input
        | Some (x, rest1) ->
            let xs, rest2 = aux rest1
            x::xs, rest2
    Parser (fun arg -> Some(aux arg))

let many1 p =           // matches one or more occurrences of p
    p >>= fun x ->
    many p >>= fun xs ->
    returnP (x::xs)

let stringP p =         // converts list of characters to string
    p |>> (fun xs -> System.String(List.toArray xs))

let letters =           // matches one or more letters
    many1 (anyOf ['A'..'Z'] <|> anyOf ['a'..'z']) |> stringP

let pint =              // matches an integer
    many1 (anyOf ['0'..'9']) |> stringP |>> int

let sepBy1 p sep =  // matches p one or more times, separated by sep
    p .>>. many (sep >>. p) |>> (fun (x,xs) -> x::xs)

let sepBy p sep =   // matches p zero or more times, separated by sep
    sepBy1 p sep <|> returnP []
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let input = "x=1,y=42,A=[1,3,4,8]"

Regex.Split(input,",(?=[A-Za-z])")  //output: [|"x=1"; "y=42"; "A=[1,3,4,8]"|]
|> Array.collect (fun x ->
    let l,v = Regex.Split(x,"=") |> fun t -> Array.head t,Array.last t  //label and value
    Regex.Split(v,",") |> Array.map (fun x -> l,Regex.Replace(x,"\[|\]","") |> int))
|> List.ofArray
```